# Crear Vistas en ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2012, ASP.NET MVC 4, C#, Entity Framework - Code Firts, los ID's de las entidades son autonumericos.

El problema es cuando creo una vista me crea un campo ProveedorId en la vista, pero no lo necesito ya que los ID's son autonumericos. Muestro mi objeto modelo.

```
public class ProveedorDto
{
    public int ProveedorId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Razón Social")]
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Dirección")]
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
}
```

Ese es el modelo con el que creo la Vista Proveedor/Create

[image: Creando vista Proveedor/Create]

Comment: Mi estimado @PedroAvila, hasta donde me quedé utilizabas MVC 5, ¿cierto? :) Esto porque en la pregunta pones que utilizas MVC 4 y en las etiquetas MVC 5, solo sería cuestión que homologues al adecuado :)

Comment: y si solamente lo borras de la vista?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que EF no esta reconociendo el valor ProveedorId como Key, por lo que a la hora de crear una vista fuertemente tipada lo ve como un campo más del formulario. Utiliza el nombre exacto de la clase osea

```
public int ProveedorDtoId {get; set;}
```

o simplemente llamalo `public int Id {get; set;}` que EF lo mapea como su Id por defecto

la otra via seria establecer la Anotación [Key] para definir el nombre que kieras como llave primaria ejemplo:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

 public class ProveedorDto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProveedorId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Razón Social")]
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Dirección")]
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
}
```

de esta forma estás definiendo que ProveedorId es tu llave. Recuerda hacer la migración después de estos cambios y dar un Rebuild a tu proyecto para que el generador de vistas no se maree. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar usando  `[NotMapped]` de la siguiente manera:

```
public class ProveedorDto
{
 [NotMapped]    
 public int ProveedorId { get; set; }

 [Display(Name = "Razón Social")]
 public string RazonSocial { get; set; }

 [Display(Name = "Dirección")]
 public string Direccion { get; set; }
}
```

Nota: El atributo `[NotMapped]` está incluido en el namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` en EF < 5.

En EF > 5 está en `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`

Comment: Probe de la forma que me indicas e igual sigue saliendo el ProveedorId en la vista del Create, lo he solucionado de la sigueinte manera. `[Key]`
              `public int ProveedorId { get; set; }` tambièn me han recomendado simplemente borrarlo de la Vista.

Comment: Que bueno que encontraste la solución. Lo de borrarlo de la vista..sirve si es una sola. Pero si tenés múltiples vistas, tenes que borrarlas en todas. No es muy óptimo. Una que podrías probar es agregar el atributo `[System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]` que te oculta el valor en todas las vistas a donde lo mapees. Tenés que mostrarlo así: `Html.EditorForModel() or  Html.EditorFor(m => m.Id)`

Answer (score 0):

Otra variante que puedes aplicar es trabajar con ViewModels.

Un ViewModel es una clases cuyas propiedades serían justamente las que necesites mostrar en la vista específica para la cual es hecho, pues en teoría puedes hacer un ViewModel para cada vista.

Otro detalle importante es que en el caso de la vista `Create`, por ejemplo pudieras emplear dos ViewModels, uno que sería el modelo que usaría la vista, y el otro sería el que recibiría el método de acción `Create` con el atributo `[HttpPost]`, esto en caso de que fuera conveniente, pero puede bastar con el mismo ViewModel para ambos métodos de acción.

De esta manera tu ViewModel para la vista `Create`, que digamos le llames `ProveedorDtoViewModel` tendría solamente las dos propiedades que deseas (`RazonSocial` y `Direccion`) y cuando vas a hacer la vista, seleccionas como `Clase de modelo` al ViewModel que creaste para esta vista (`ProveedorDtoViewModel`).

Entonces, para pasar la información de tu Entidad (`ProveedorDto`) al ViewModel correspondiente (`ProveedorDtoViewModel`) puedes hacerlo manualmente o empleando la herramienta [Automapper](http://automapper.org/).

Sé que con esta explicación quizás no resuelvas mucho, pero al menos es una introducción y espero te sea útil.

Un saludo.